# Conjugacy classes in $Q_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that in the quaternion group $Q_8$, there are $5$ conjugacy classes, $2$ of which are $\{1\}$ and $\{-1\}$. Why are $1$ and $-1$ in their own conjugacy classes rather than a single one: $\{1, -1\}$? Thanks!

Comment: Because they are both in the center. Observe that $g1g^{-1}=1$ for all $g\in G$ with **any** group $G$. Hence $1$ is always in a conjugacy class by itself.